# Отправка post через jQuery

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Вот у меня гемор с отправкой `$.post()` в **jQuery**.

Есть такой **html** код:

```
`<div class='Stats'>
                    <center><b>Статы</b></center>
                    <table id='evContainer'>
                      <td><td><i>Стат</i></td> <td><i>Ген</i></td> <td><i>EVi></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>НР:</td> <td>19</td> <td width='30'>0</td> <td>19 <a href='2' id='evo_hp'><img src='./style/another/plus.jpg' width='10' height='10'></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Атака:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0 <a href='2' id='evo_atk'><img src='./style/another/plus.jpg' width='10' height='10'></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Защита:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0 <a href='2' id='evo_def'><img src='./style/another/plus.jpg' width='10' height='10'></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Скорость:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0 <a href='2' id='evo_speed'><img src='./style/another/plus.jpg' width='10' height='10'></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Спец. Атака:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0 <a href='2' id='evo_sp_atk'><img src='./style/another/plus.jpg' width='10' height='10'></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Спец. Защита:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0 <a href='2' id='evo_sp_def'><img src='./style/another/plus.jpg' width='10' height='10'></a></td></tr>
                      <tr><td><b>&nbsp;EV: 0</b></td> <td></td> <td></td></tr>
                    </table>  
</div> 
`
```

Как мы видим у нас есть ссылку такого рода:

`<a href='2' id='ev_hp'><img ..></a>`

Значит, *href* отвечает за ID столбик в **MySQL**, а *id* показывает, что именно будет изменено в бд. И я попытался отправлять запросы на изменения через **jQuery** Таким образом:

```
`
$.post('./ajax/check_ev_plus.php',{id_pok:$(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('id'):'zapros'},function(ev_error){
..Обрабатываем ответ..
});
`
```

Как видно с кода **jQuery** я попытался отправить пост с тем именем, что показано в id ссылке, но у меня ничего не получилось, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Вот что принимает check_ev_plus.php

```
$hp = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['evo_hp'])); //hp $atk = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['evo_atk'])); //Атака $def = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['evo_def'])); //Защита $speed = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['evo_speed'])); //Скорость $sp_atk = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['evo_sp_atk'])); //Спец. Атака $sp_def = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['evo_sp_def'])); //Спец. Защита $id_pok = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['id_pok'])); //ID Покемон
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот код отправки видно - а куда он прицеплен?, когда он срабатывает и что у вас this- соответсвенно щас непонятно

и вообще att на сколько я помню нет в jquery есть attr

то есть попробуйте так

```
$.post('./ajax/check_ev_plus.php',{id_pok:$(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('id'):'zapros'},function(ev_error){
..Обрабатываем ответ..
});
```

а зачем вы сделали вот так  $(this).attr('id'):'zapros'  - ?? не проще 'zapros':$(this).attr('id')

а уже в php сценарии проверять значение zapros - и делать логику??

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатался, там действительно должно быть attr, но оно не помогает, не могу понять почему.

Comment: скрипт check_ev_plus.php - каиенибудь переменные получает или вообще запрос не происходит?

куда вещается данный код - на какое событие какого элемента??

Comment: Да, check_ev_plus.php получает. Щас добавлю в вопрос его скрипт. Но я проверял, им не приходит значение. Поэтому думаю толку это мало даст (

Comment: $.post('./ajax/check_ev_plus.php',{id_pok:$(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('id'):'zapros'},function(ev_error){
..Обрабатываем ответ..
});  ----ЕЩЕ РАЗ СПРАШИВАЮ - вот ЭТО ОТКУДА?????????????

Comment: $('#evContainer a').click(function(){ }); А толку? Если я все перепробовал и именно в запросе ошибка.. $(this).attr('id') Вот этот атрибут не хочет отправлять... Вот и все..

Comment: Я немножко не уловил, только вторая часть данных не приходит, или та, что помечена id_pok тоже?

Comment: Отмену выполнение события сделайте:

    $('#evContainer a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // дальше ваш код
    });

Comment: переместл код в ваш вопрос - комент удадли, исправил свой ответ